# URL Rewrite Default Document Web Page to SEO URL

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, webforms

I have started using ASP.NET Routing for my site. I have been registering routes via the Application_Start() in my Global.asax file.

i.e.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ROUTE-ABOUT", "about", "~/About.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("ROUTE-CONTACT", "contact", "~/Contact.aspx");
//etc...
```

This is working perfectly for the About and Contact pages.

### What I Want:

My home page is Home.aspx and what I wanted to do is rewrite anyone that visits

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/Home.aspx
```

to

```
http://localhost/mysite.com/Home
```

### What I've Tried

- I have my site running in my local IIS v7.5 on my machine (full
  administrator privileges).
- I have added the following to my Web.config

**Web.config**

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HOMETOSEO" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="Home\.aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="home" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying to get this to work I eventually managed to get it working using the following entry in the `Web.config` and `Application_Start()` of the `Global.asax` file:

**Web.config**

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="default" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="(.*)Home\.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="home" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="lower" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" /> 
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    BuildStaticRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    //...
}

public void BuildStaticRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //...
    routes.MapPageRoute("ROUTE-HOME", "home", "~/Home.aspx");
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS v7.5 you can add this in web.config

```
<system.webServer>  
<rewrite>
            <rules>                
                <rule name="HOMETOSEO" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Home" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Home.aspx" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

When you type `http://mysite.com/Home`, it will display `http://mysite.com/Home.aspx`. Is that what you are after or the other way around?

Comment: The other way around. From http://localhost/MySite/Home.aspx to http://localhost/MySite/Home thanks

Comment: I tried it with <match url="^Home.aspx" /> and <action type="Rewrite" url="Home" /> and it didn't rewrite it for me. Is there anything else I may be missing? The Url Rewrite component is visible when I view my site in IIS Manager on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a custom route by inheriting from RouteBase - so in your case it would look something like this

```
public class HomeRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("home.aspx"))
        {
            httpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"; //Optional 301 redirect
            httpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = "Home";
            httpContext.Response.End();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then in you register routes you would have

```
routes.Add("HomeUrl", new HomeRoute());
```

So that any request to /Home.aspx would automatically redirect to /Home - obviously with a bit of extra work you could make this a bit more generic for any .aspx request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tested your code and the code never seems to enter the if-statement. I definitely have added the call to register the route against the RouteCollection in the Application_Start().

Comment: Interesting..did you register it before all other routes? If not, give that try - I have something similar working in production code.

Comment: Yes, I have even commented all other route registration's out but still can't get it to work. Damn.